# disable class but not the content on smaller device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a affix sidebar which i hide when the page opened from smaller screen, but when i added the main content it hides behind the sidebar so i add margin-left:200px; on the content now it working properly on bigger screen but when i open the page from smaller screen i got really thin content

[image]

[image]

this is my sidebar

```
    <div class="main-nav">
<div class="row">
<div class="hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
    <div class="col-md-2 affix">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-dollar"> </i> Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-users"> </i> Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"> </i> Lorem Ipsum</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-unlock"> </i> Lorem Ipsum</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.main-nav {
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

}

and this is part of my main content

pastebin com 7mxAzDTi

the css

```
.main-content {
margin-left: 220px;
margin-right: 10px;
min-height: 800px;
```

}

Comment: You failed to give us your desired result.... I would *imagine*  that you would want to use the built in bootstrap grid system to change it so on the small devices it expands the full width of the screen and then the content moves underneath. That's all assumption though bc you didn't state what you wanted.

Comment: i'm sorry, this is my desired result http://prntscr.com/ft0cb9, i'm using margin-left: 220px; on the content because if i don't the sidebar just hide underneath the content on larger screen like this https://prnt.sc/ft0csz instead of this https://prnt.sc/ft0d65

Comment: You probably forgot to reduce the `margin-left: 220px` on smaller screens to 10px or something

Comment: adding `@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .main-content {
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
} ` fixed the issue